# Recommendation for books on math similar to Robert Kanigel's "Man who knew infinity"

Tags: reference-request

Recently my friend gifted me Robert's Kanigel book "Man who knew infinity" and i loved it.I have read genius of RAMANUJAN .I have got interested in books on mathematics . If anyone know special books on life of math geniuses . Please let me know i will be grateful ..Thanks

Comment: [The Man Who Loved Only Numbers: The Story of Paul Erdos and the Search for Mathematical Truth](http://www.amazon.com/Man-Who-Loved-Only-Numbers/dp/0786884061/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1415726483&sr=8-1&keywords=paul+erdos) and [My Brain is Open](http://www.amazon.com/MY-BRAIN-OPEN-Mathematical-Journeys/dp/0684859807/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1415726533&sr=8-1&keywords=my+brain+is+open) are two good ones on Paul Erdos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also read these books. I think you will be fascinated with these books.
You can try:

$1)$ [Mathematical Thought From Ancient To Modern Times vol 3](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=8YaBuGcmLb0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=MORRIS+KLINE+Mathematical+Thought+From+Ancient+To+Modern+Times&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIvouutNfYxwIVRAWOCh0whwG2#v=onepage&q=MORRIS%20KLINE%20Mathematical%20Thought%20From%20Ancient%20To%20Modern%20Times&f=false)

$2)$[Mathematical Thought From Ancient To Modern Times vol 1](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=lbPN34fg760C&printsec=frontcover&dq=MORRIS+KLINE+Mathematical+Thought+From+Ancient+To+Modern+Times&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAWoVChMIvouutNfYxwIVRAWOCh0whwG2#v=onepage&q=MORRIS%20KLINE%20Mathematical%20Thought%20From%20Ancient%20To%20Modern%20Times&f=false)

$3)$[Mathematical Thought From Ancient To Modern Times vol 2](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=XXMR6EqqjgwC&dq=MORRIS+KLINE+Mathematical+Thought+From+Ancient+To+Modern+Times&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBWoVChMIvouutNfYxwIVRAWOCh0whwG2)

$4)$[Paul J. Nahin - An Imaginary Tale The Story of i the Square Root of Minus One](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=C_TXtiO4ppwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Paul+J.+Nahin+-+An+Imaginary+Tale+The+Story+of+i+the+Square+Root+of+Minus+One&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAWoVChMI_LvfydnYxwIVRI6OCh0Ttgar#v=onepage&q=Paul%20J.%20Nahin%20-%20An%20Imaginary%20Tale%20The%20Story%20of%20i%20the%20Square%20Root%20of%20Minus%20One&f=false)

I got so much enchanted with these books that I read these frequently.

Answer (score 2):

Winfried Scharlau wrote a biography about **Alexander Grothendieck**, who had a deep influence on modern algebraic geometry. The title is "Wer ist Alexander Grothendieck? Anarchie, Mathematik, Spiritualität(, Einsamkeit)". As far as I know it was planned to appear in three volumes. The [first one](http://www.scharlau-online.de/DOKS/ankuendigung_anarchie.pdf) and the [third one](http://www.scharlau-online.de/DOKS/ankuendigung_spiritualitaet.pdf) volume already appeared. The last word of the title was not present yet in the first volume. I guess Scharlau decided later to add a fourth volume. As far as I know, the first volume has to be ordered directly from the author, while the third one is available in bookstores.

Unfortunately both appeared first in German. Though, the first volume has been translated to English by Melissa Schneps. Its title is "Alexander Grothendieck? Anarchy, Mathematics, Spirituality, Solitude".

They are not merely about Grothendieck's achievements in mathematics, but cover more aspects about his life, as the title indicates.

Comment: The third one is currently being translated by Melissa Schneps. You can see updates as well as help fund the translation [here](http://www.gofundme.com/7ldiwo).

Comment: @RobertCardona Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Men of Mathematics 
Book by Eric Temple Bell

http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Men_of_Mathematics.html?id=BLFL3coT5i4C

Book - Beautiful Mind
By  Sylvia Nasar